# 90s short story featuring military guy befriending blue alien that reproduces by fission

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a story that was in one of the major sci-fi magazines in the nineties. There was a military guy and he went to a planet and meet a blue alien who didn't speak, but they formed a very strong bond. He decided to resign and stay on the planet, and the humans left him a button to push if he ever wanted to leave. Then one day he came home to discover the blue alien dying, torn apart and writhing in pain, and he very sadly put it out of its misery... And then it turned out that its race reproduces by fission, it wasn't injured at all, and he'd killed his friend unnecessarily. So he pushed the button and left.